# Strong induction different assumptions

Tags: induction

I have a question regarding strong induction. I've seen examples on proofs that assume that P(n) is true for all n that is smaller or equal than k and thereby dealing with k+1 in the inductive step followed.
In some other other case i have seen examples where it is assumed that P(n) is true for all n < k followed by induction proof on the k.

Can someone tell me why this is different and which one is correct approach?

Comment: What's the difference between the two methods you have stated?

Comment: sorry, ive edited my question, re-read the last part.

Answer (score 1):

It varies depending on the problem.

Ordinary induction
proves n assuming the truth
for n-1.

Mildly strong induction,
to prove truth for n,
might have to assume the truth
for n-1 and n-2.

Somewhat strong induction,
to prove truth for n,
might have to assume the truth
for a fixed number
of predecessors
n-1, n-2, ..., n-k.

Really strong induction,
to prove truth for n,
might have to assume the truth
for a number
of predecessors
that depends on n:
n-1, n-2, ..., n-k(n).

And finally,
for the
traditionally strong induction,
to prove truth for n,
might have to assume the truth
for all of its predecessors:
n-1, n-2, ..., 2, 1.

It all depends on what you are trying to prove.

Comment: I understand the 4 first versions of induction, but could you write a sentence or two about the last one. I mean, isnt it the same version 3?

Comment: For the third one, an example might be using the first $\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$ predecessors. I agree that my phrasing is not as precise as it might be.